# Swing application multiple threads sharing data and creating evemts

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, simulation

Currently I am working on a Swing application in Java. Lets call this program Simulator. My task is to
deliver packages to their destination by trucks. I have a thread which calculates scheduling of the trucks(which package when to deliver).This thread can run in some cases very long. In a second thread(calculator thread) I am calculating the step of simulation. These two threads should communicate with each other. The algorithm thread sends  plans and trucks to the calculator thread and  calculator thread sends back free trucks to the algorithm thread. The simulation ends when the calculator thread ends its work. My question is related to drawing of the simulation. Where should  a call the drawing of the components? In the same thread where the steps are calculated? Third thread for drawing? Any other possible options?

Comment: Use `SwingWorker`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20swingworker).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd use a separate thread for drawing. Do the drawing you need in an infinite loop then call `Thread.sleep(1000)` to make it update approximately once a second.